# Statistical power and sample size determination for two sample (unequal variance) welch t-test?

Tags: r

The command for two sample t-test (equal variance pooled std dev.) is

```
power.t.test(n=, delta=, sd=, type="two.sample")
```

How do I compute statistical power given two sample of **unequal variance** and **sample number**?

Comment: Are you trying to determine the necessary number of samples to reach a certain level of power, or are you saying that you know the sample sizes and want to compute the power of the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `power_t_test()` function from the `MESS` package.

For example, to compute the required sample sizes when you have a 1:2 ratio of individuals, sd's 1 and 3 and an effect size of 1.2 is (for power 80%)

```
> MESS::power_t_test(n=NULL, sd=1, power=.8, ratio=2, sd.ratio=3, delta=1.2)

     Two-sample t test power calculation with unequal sizes 

              n = 14.35824, 28.71648
          delta = 1.2
             sd = 3
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is vector of number in each group
```

To compute the power you'd set `power=NULL` and specify the `n` instead just as for the regular `power.t.test()` function.

```
> MESS::power_t_test(n=20, sd=1, power=NULL, ratio=2, sd.ratio=3, delta=1.2)

     Two-sample t test power calculation with unequal sizes 

              n = 20, 40
          delta = 1.2
             sd = 3
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.9149541
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is vector of number in each group
```

Comment: yes, this solved my probelm. Surprisingly "ratio" and "sd.ratio" wasn't mentioned in Rstutio help

Comment: They are not part of the `power.t.test` function that ships with base R. You need an extended function similar to `power_t_test()`

Comment: I will use these command for two sample (unequal variance) pwr.t2n.test(n1=NULL, n2= NULL, d = NULL, sig.level = 0.05, power = NULL,alternative=c("two.sided", "less","greater"))  in combination with ES.t.two(m1 = NULL, m2 = NULL, sd1 = NULL, sd2 = NULL, n1 = NULL,
  n2 = NULL, t = NULL, se1 = NULL, se2 = NULL, df = NULL,
  alternative = c("two.sided", "one.sided")) to estimate the cohen d.